# Как прочитать локальный файл с помощью Javascript?

Tags: javascript

пишу небольшое расширение для Mozilla Firefox. Нужно прочитать элементарный текстовый файл (или json) находящийся на ЖД компьютера. Перепробовал все варианты, которые нашел в интернете, в том числе на этом сайте. Безуспешно. Подскажите где найти простой и рабочий пример. Не думал, что это так сложно.

Comment: напрямую никак. нужен Input type=file, чтобы пользователь сам мог выбрать файл

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_files